# Use wireguard client as default gateway of another (server in docker)

Tags: docker, routing, wireguard

almost same as this article
[Wireguard use one client as gateway of another](https://serverfault.com/questions/1088689/wireguard-use-one-client-as-gateway-of-another)
but i have wireguard in docker so i can't understand how to solve my routing problem

peer1 --- wireguard_server(in docker) --- peer2 --- internet

peer1: 10.14.1.2
wireguard_server: 10.14.1.1
peer2: 10.14.1.3

My docker-compose.yml

```
---
version: "2.1"
services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard:latest
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Nicosia
      - SERVERURL=auto #optional
      - SERVERPORT=51820 #optional
      - PEERS=2 #optional
      - PEERDNS=auto #optional
      - INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.14.1.0 #optional
      - ALLOWEDIPS=0.0.0.0/0 #optional
      - PERSISTENTKEEPALIVE_PEERS=all #optional
      - LOG_CONFS=true #optional
    volumes:
      - /root/wireguard/config:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules #optional
    ports:
      - 51820:51820/udp
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped
```

My actions on wireguard_server

```
docker exec -it wireguard bash
ip rule add from 10.14.1.2 lookup 200
ip route add default dev wg0 table 200
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 - execute on host, not in docker
```

After that i change wg0.conf for peer2

```
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/5,8.0.0.0/7,10.14.1.3/32,11.0.0.0/8,12.0.0.0/6,16.0.0.0/4,32.0.0.0/3,64.0.0.0/2,128.0.0.0/1
```

i don't see any traffic on peer2 from peer1

Comment: Working on something similar, but maybe in an lxc or even a vm. I hope someone helps out. My knowledge of routing tables, especially inside a docker container, is dreadfully incomplete.